# Элементы окружения в тегах

Tags: поддержка, метки, вопросы

Стоит ли указывать в тегах такие элементы окружения, как ОС (например)?
Делаешь выборку по тегу linux - а там все, что только может быть.

Примеры:

[Как можно остановить приложение Linux после нажатия Ctrl+C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873659/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-linux-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-ctrlc)

[Тело в http ответе приходит только после множества запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870240/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2-http-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

[Ошибка сегментирования (С++)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840831/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A1)

Comment: Да вроде по делу стоят.

Comment: 1 - вопрос именно для Linux специфичный. 2 - используются системные вызовы. 3 - насколько я вижу ничего специфичного нет, разве что ncurses, и то его с определенными танцами с бубном наверное и под Windows можно прикрутить.

Comment: @insolor, 1 - signal в std есть, 2 - да, только вопрос о другом, 3 - еще раз прочитайте, откуда там ncurses появилось :)

Comment: @isnullxbh, 3 - в упор не вижу, зачем там curses. Собственно, убрал метку linux. По 1 и 2 нельзя сказать однозначно, что метка linux не нужна.

Comment: Мне тут стало интересно. А Вы видите эту страницу [так же](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5RKa.png)?

Comment: @alexolut, забавно.. ) Нет, я такого бэйджа у себя не вижу

Comment: В принципе это логично. Просто стало интересно, не налагано ли тут :)

Comment: @alexolut, возможно я ошибся.. Вижу) Имеется ввиду "новый участник" на мете?

Comment: Ну, я на картинке обвёл там красными кругами (FHRC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, для вопросов, касающихся особенностей конкретной ОС, или когда автор ожидает решение именно под эту ОС. Это описано довольно четко в tag wiki: [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info), [windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/info).

Если вы разбираетесь в предметной области и на 100% уверены, что вопрос никак не привязан к ОС, возьмите и удалите метку. Но будьте готовы к тому, что автор воспримет это... не очень радостно, так как удаление популярной метки уменьшает потенциальное количество просмотров вопроса.

Comment: Если ответ получен, автору уже обычно пофигу какие там метки кто правил. Более того, уведомлений о правке при редактировании только лишь меток автору вопроса не приходит.